# How can I justify that $\int_0^{+\infty} f(t) \sin(t) dt$ diverges when $f$ is a polynomial?

Tags: calculus

I have this integral, $\int_0^{+\infty} f(t) \sin(t) dt$ where $f$ is a polynomial. Integrating by parts as many times as the degree of the polynomial, we can see that this integral doesn't converge. However this method is a bit cumbersome to write down formally, do you have any others in mind?

Comment: diverges? as in has a value $+\infty$ or $-\infty$? it doesn't diverge in this sense. the integral doesn't exist. neither the negative part or positive part of the function has a finite integral....

Comment: 0 is a polynomial too...

Comment: @Frank: ok, I meant "doesn't exist".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As improper integral, this should be the 
$$ \lim_{a\to+\infty}\underbrace{\int_0^af(t)\sin t\,\mathrm dt}_{=:F(t)}.$$
Assume $f$ is a nonconstant polynomial. Then for $a$ big enough, $f(t)>1$ for all $t>a$ or $f(t)<-1$ for all $t>a$.
Hence $|F((k+1)\pi)-F(k\pi)|>\left|\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\sin t\,\mathrm dt\right|=2$ for $k$ big enough, makeing convergence impossible.

Comment: Great, Cauchy's criterion, I thought of that but I thought it would be more painful to write down. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$f(t)$ goes to either positive or negative infinity as $t$ grows, assuming it has degree at least $1$. That means that there is some $T$ such that $|f(t)|>10^9$ as long as $t>T$.

Choose an $n\in \Bbb N$ such that $2\pi n>T$. Then compare
$$
\int_0^{2\pi n} f(t) \sin t\: dt
$$
and
$$
\int_0^{2\pi (n+1/2)} f(t) \sin t\: dt
$$
They must differ by at least $10^9$. The same for the last one and
$$
\int_0^{2\pi (n+1)} f(t) \sin t\: dt
$$
So the integral cannot converge.